# working with functions that takes non-zero natural numbers

Tags: idris

I am trying to define a function (`congruentialMethod`) in Idris that amongst others applies modulus arithmetic on some of the arguments provided to my function. Modulus arithmetic requires that the second argument to be non-zero, so I have attempted to utilize `modNatNZ` and add a proof to my function type signature. However, I feel my attempt comes about very clunky.

First of all, when I define the value that ends up being the second arg to the modulus function (`let m : Nat = 2147483647`), -I have to perform some clunky case matching to convince Idris that the value is bigger than zero. If I don't do this then type checking takes forever.

Second, I don't really understand why I have to provide a proof when I call my function (`congruentialMethod`). I specified the proof as `auto` in the function signature thinking Idris would be able to infer it.

```
module Random

%default total

getUnixEpoch : IO Nat
getUnixEpoch = do time <- foreign FFI_C "#(unsigned long)time(NULL)" (IO Int)
                  pure $ fromInteger $ cast time

congruentialMethod : (seed : Nat) -> (a : Nat) -> (b : Nat) -> (m : Nat) -> {auto prf : (m = Z) -> Void} -> Stream Double
congruentialMethod seed a b m {prf} =
  (cast seed) / (cast m) :: loop seed
  where
    loop : (prev : Nat) -> Stream Double
    loop prev = let n = modNatNZ (a * prev + b) m prf
                in (cast n) / (cast m) :: loop n

main : IO ()
main = do time <- getUnixEpoch
          putStrLn $ "seed: " ++ (cast time)
          let a : Nat = 16807
          let b : Nat = 0
          let m : Nat = 2147483647
          case m of
               Z => ?shouldnt_happen
               S m' => do let random_number_stream = congruentialMethod time a b (S m') {prf = SIsNotZ}
                          ?continue
```

**Can I somehow avoid passing a proof to my `congruentialMethod` function? and is there a less clunky way to convince Idris that `let m : Nat = 2147483647` is bigger than zero *(rather than using a case match)*?**

*EDIT: Another problem with this code seems to be that performing calculations with `Nat` is extremely slow. Using `Int`, `mod` and changing the functions to being `partial` makes it fast to generate numbers. Obviously being forced to defining functions as `partial` sucks.. But perhaps this is material for another question....*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idris has a very hard time inferring `Not` proofs, because they are functions, and Idris just doesn't try to infer functions, because functions are quite complicated. The standard library has already thought of your situtation. We have [`Prelude.Nat.IsSucc`](https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/current/prelude_doc/docs/Prelude.Nat.html#Prelude.Nat.IsSucc):

```
data IsSucc : Nat -> Type where
  ItIsSucc : IsSucc (S n)
```

This works with `auto`, but the existing `Nat` functions aren't compatible with it, so we use a bit of glue.

```
isSuccNotZero : IsSucc n -> Not (n = Z)
isSuccNotZero {n = S _} ItIsSucc Refl impossible
```

And that's it:

```
congruentialMethod : (seed : Nat) -> (a : Nat) -> (b : Nat) ->
                     (m : Nat) -> {auto prf : IsSucc m} -> Stream Double
congruentialMethod seed a b m {prf} =
  (cast seed / cast m) :: (congruentialMethod (modNatNZ (a * seed + b) m $ isSuccNotZero prf) a b m)
```

The usage site will now infer `prf`. However, with a number that big, the compiler still chokes, as you've seen in your edit. It will eventually get it right, but that'll take a while. I don't have a solution for that.